# Efficient EMF database Integration

Tags: database, eclipse, eclipse-rcp, emf, teneo

I want to save/load an emf model to/from database. The tool that persistently pops whenever I search for such a topic is [Teneo](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Teneo) which I used and created a database schema to and from which I can save and load. But My main worries are the produced schema, which is too complicated it only consists of one huge table with many indexes that made me worry that the performance is not going to be ok. So, my question is "Is there an efficient way to map an emf model to an efficient database schema either by using Teneo or any other tool ?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Teneo provides a JOINED inheritance mapping, This solved my problem to some extent. The schema generated is huge, so still do not know if the output schema is optimal or not.